# Vue.js transition-group deleting and adding again

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I have a list of forms in a Vue single page template.  The template loads content as arrays asynchronously which are then iterated over to create the forms.  the list is the child of a `<transition-group>`.  Each form has an up/down button enabling them to be moved up and down the list; when up/down is clicked the form above/below swaps with the clicked form using a transition animation.

The animation for the list is absolutely fine when the page is loaded with asynchronous content during the template's `created()` hook.

However, when the list is empty during `created()` or where all the forms in the list are deleted and a new form is subsequently added, the order animation ceases to operate.  Nothing else breaks, all the reactivity etc. is completely fine.  Given the below, is there a workaround to this bug?

I'll try and provide the briefest stub that I can below should it be useful:

[HTML]

```html
<template>
...
<transition-group v-if="sections.length"
                          name="flip-list"
                          tag="div">
  <div v-for="(section, i) in sortedOrder"
       :key="sortedOrder[i].id>
    <div>
       <button @click.prevent="decrementOrder(section.order, i)">
         <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
       </button>
       <button @click.prevent="incrementOrder(section.order, i)">
         <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
       </button>
       ... FORM FIELDS ETC ...
    </div>
  </div>
</transition-group>
...
</template>
```

[JS]

```
computed: {
  sortedOrder () {
      let sorted = this.sections
      return sorted.sort((a, b) => { return a.order - b.order })
    }  
},
methods: {
   ...
   addSection () {
      let newSection = {
        id: -1,
        order: this.sections.length,
        ...
      }
      let i = this.sections.push(newSection) - 1
      ...
    },
    deleteSection (id) {
      let wasSpliced = 0
      this.sections.forEach(function (section, i) {
        if (section.id === id) {
          this.sections.splice(i, 1)
          if (this.sections.length && this.sections.length > i) { 
            --this.sections[i].order
          }
          wasSpliced = 1
        } else if (wasSpliced) {
          --this.sections[i].order
        }
      }.bind(this))
    },
    decrementOrder (order, i) {
      if (order > 0) {
        this.sections.forEach((it, j) => {
          if (it.order + 1 === order) {
            ++this.sections[j].order
            --this.sections[i].order
          }
        })
      }
    },
    incrementOrder (order, i) {
      if (order <= this.sections.length - 1) {
        this.sections.forEach((it, j) => {
          if (it.order - 1 === order) {
            --this.sections[j].order
            ++this.sections[i].order
          }
        })
      }
    }
    ...
}
```

[CSS]

```
...css
.flip-list-move {
transition: transform 1s;
}
```